# NSJSONSerialization compiler warning

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

I am using JSON to populate a mapView with markers.

At method `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

the compiler is showing an alert:

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 'NSJSONReadingOptions' (aka 'enum NSJSONReadingOptions')
```

at lines

```
categorias_first = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data_for_first_connection options:nil error:nil];
categorias_second = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data_for_second_connection options:nil error:nil];
categorias_third = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data_for_third_connection options:nil error:nil];
```

This is the whole method code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //if data received network indicator not visible
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    if(connection==first_connection) {

        categorias_first = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data_for_first_connection options:nil error:nil];

    }
    else if(connection==second_connection){

        categorias_second = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data_for_second_connection options:nil error:nil];
    }
    else if(connection==third_connection){

        categorias_third = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data_for_third_connection options:nil error:nil];
    }

}
```

Any help to avoid the warning is welcome.

Comment: Pass `0`, not `nil` for the `options` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil` treated as `((void*)0)` and has pointer type, but `NSJSONReadingOptions` (as an enum) is a integer type.

replace `options:nil` by `options:0`

EX :

```
    categorias_first = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data_for_first_connection options:0 error:nil];
     ........
```